# Is the heat semigroup on a manifold the limit of the heat semigroups associated to a compact exhaustion?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, riemannian-geometry, operator-theory, vector-bundles, laplacian

Let $M$ be a paracompact Riemannian manifold, and $E \to M$ a Hermitian vector bundle endowed with a Hermitian connection $\nabla$. Write $M$ as an exhaustion $\bigcup _{j \ge 0} U_j$ with relatively compact open subsets with smooth boundaries.

If $L^2 (M, E)$ is the space of square-integrable sections in $E$, let $L : L^2 (M, E) \to L^2 (M, E)$ be the (densely defined) Friedrichs extension of $\nabla^* \nabla$ (with $\nabla^*$ the formal adjoint of $\nabla$). By the Hille-Yoshida theorem, this operator generates a $C_0$-semigroup $(\mathrm e ^{-tL}) _{t \ge 0}$ of contractions in $L^2 (M, E)$.

Similarly, one may perform the same construction on $U_j$ and obtain the operator $L_j$ and the associated semigroup $(\mathrm e ^{-tL_j}) _{t \ge 0}$ of contractions in $L^2 (M, E_j)$, for every $j \ge 0$.

> Is there any way in which $\mathrm e ^{-tL_j}$ converges to $\mathrm e ^{-tL}$ for every $t \ge 0$?

I know that this is true when $E = M \times \mathbb C$ with the usual Hermitian structure, and $\nabla$ is just the differential operator acting on smooth functions. The proof, though, relies on the existence of the heat kernel, on its property of being the minimal positive fundamental solution of the heat equation, and on using the monotone convergence theorem (to define the heat kernel of $\mathrm e ^{-tL}$ as the pointwise limit of the heat kernels of $\mathrm e ^{-tL_j}$). These tools are clearly not available in general bundles, so what to do then? I have tried to use the theorems in chapter VIII of volume 1 of Reed & Simon, but the hypotheses therein are not satisfied in my setting.

Comment: I think there are some general theorems about convergence/approximation of $C_0$-semigroups that are defined on changing domains. [This book](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1345.47001) by Adam Bobrowski contains various results on approximation and convergence of semigroups (but I'm not sure whether one of the theorems there answers your question).

Comment: @JochenGlueck: You've nailed it, the problem is that the underlying domains change. For instance, one theorem in Reed & Simon requires the generators $L_j$ and $L$ to have a common core - which is not possible here. The other theorems therein have similar types of requirements that are not met in this situation.

Comment: The results for non-densely defined forms are only sketched there, but I think the article *A Canonical Decomposition of Quadratic Forms with Applications to Monotone Convergence Theorems* by Barry Simon should give you all the necessary tools. You have monotone convergence of the associated quadratic forms, the only difficulty is that they are not densely defined in $L^2(M;E)$.

Comment: Echoing @MaoWao's comment, there is also a [recent article](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A7285977) ([arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.03774)) by the complex Vo(i)gts which deals with convergence of non-densely defined forms. They even consider non-symmetric forms; the reference list there could probably give you a lot of useful hints to more classical results.

Comment: @JochenGlueck: You've titillated my curiosity: why are the Vo(i)gt "complex"?

Comment: @AlexM.: Well, the one without an i ([Hendrik Vogt](https://www.mathgenealogy.org/id.php?id=59001)) is real, and the one with an i ([Jürgen Voigt](https://www.mathgenealogy.org/id.php?id=21500)) is probably imaginary (although it is safe to say he exists - for instance, he was the PhD supervisor of the real Vogt; I've also met him in real life on many occasions). So together they are, well, complex... ;-) [I'm not sure who first came up with this joke - but I've heard it several times in the operator semigroups community.]